# Move localhost magento to another locallhost

Tags: jquery, magento, magento-1.7, localhost, local

I want to know how to move my local magento to another computer in another local host i already move it and copy my db but when i open
the admin page i cant access to the other options like cms products
and that stuff i really need help im pretty new in magento i'll
appreciate it.

Please Help!**

When i enter to my home page i cant see my subcategories only can se
my categories But i can   access to that pages like cell phones
example, i only what to copy to another computer not to live server
only to a another localhost but in a different computer.

Comment: Magento questions should be asked on [magento.se]

Answer (score 0):

check setting rewrite mode is enable or not.

domain name is consider as string.
So You have to setup vertual host in apache.it will help u.